# Why aren't there any coproducts in the category of $\bf{Fields}$?

Tags: field-theory, category-theory

Well the question is stated in the title. 
I dont know much about field theory and i was suprised when i read it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_rings)

please provide some examples

thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't know any field theory, why do you find this statement surprising?

Comment: What Wikipedia in fact says is "**Field** has neither products nor coproducts." This is slightly weaker than the claim that it doesn't have *any* products or coproducts, and in fact some trivial cases do exist. For example, the coproduct of $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Chris: good point.  I took the question to be an explanation of the quoted fact (for coproducts, but of course the same argument works for products).  If the OP wants to know necessary and sufficient for a coproduct of fields to exist, s/he should clarify accordingly.  (This is actually a pretty good question, now that I think about it: it has to do with tensor products, composita and so forth...)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I'd quite like to see an answer to that question! (Also, isn't it in principle possible for the coproduct to exist in the category of fields but be different from the coproduct in the category of commutative rings?)

Comment: @Zhen: sure, that is (like most things!) "in principle possible".  However, when the coproduct exists in the category of rings *and is a field*, then I think it is *in principle impossible* that this is anything else than the coproduct in the category of fields. :)  By the way, please go ahead and ask the followup question, if you are interested.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark That's entirely true, by general nonsense involving considerations of hom-sets. I've posted the question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146000).

Comment: Dear @Pete:  yes,  if the tensor product of two fields over their common prime field is a field, then that field is the required coproduct. But it requires some analysis to decide whether the tensor product of the given fields is a field or not...

Comment: @Georges: Not only do I know this, but given that you have read my field theory notes, I think you know that I know this. :)

Comment: Dear @Pete, sorry, no offense meant . I was answering your comment "...then I think it is in principle impossible that this is anything else than the coproduct in the category of fields". Since you had written "...I think... in principle..." I thought that some readers might conclude that you were not quite sure. I suppose you were just joking , since there was a smiley, ... :-)

Comment: @Georges: no offense taken!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Among other things, a coproduct of objects $F_1$ and $F_2$ in a category is an object $F$ together with morphisms $\iota_1: F_1 \rightarrow F$, $\iota_2: F_2 \rightarrow F$.

In order to have a homomorphism between two fields $K$ and $L$, $K$ and $L$ must have the same characteristic.  Thus for instance $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ 
 (for any prime $p$) cannot have a coproduct in the category of fields.  (**Added**: they can't have a product either, for almost exactly the same reasons.)

Comment: Ok i get that we cant find a object with two arrow from $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z/pZ}$ but doesn't this simply mean that the pathcategory $(\triangle\downarrow T)$, (T is the functor with the field above) is empty, which inturn should imply that the coproduct is the 0 field, or am i missing something and perhaps there is no 0 field?

Comment: [well...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element)

Comment: @user25470: Yes, there is no $0$ field.  (@anon: the "field with one element", whatever it is, is not an element of the category of fields!)

Comment: I know, I know. ("if such a field could exist")

Comment: very well, i accept your answer as true, but i dont really understand why. In the rings we accept 0 as multiplicative identity, why can't we do the same for fields?

Answer (score 6):

As Pete said, two fields $F_1$ and $F_2$ can only have a coproduct if they have the same prime field $F$ ($F = \mathbb{Q}$ or $F = \mathbb{F}_p$).

a) If the $F$-algebra $F_1 \otimes_F F_2$ is a field, then it is a coproduct of $F_1$ and $F_2$ in the category of fields.
The simplest examples are the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^2} \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p} \mathbb{F}_{p^3} = \mathbb{F}_{p^6}$
It is however a delicate question to decide  whether  $F_1 \otimes_F F_2$ is a field: see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82083/when-is-the-tensor-product-of-two-fields-a-field) for many examples and non-examples.

b) If $F_1 \otimes_F F_2$ is not a field and if a coproduct $F_1 \sqcup F_2$ of $F_1$ and $F_2$ exists, we have a ring morphism $F_1 \otimes_F F_2 \to F_1 \sqcup F_2$. But I don’t know if it  really possible that $F_1 \sqcup F_2$ exists if $F_1 \otimes_F F_2$ is not a field.